# How to define prop types in typescript in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

I have created a vue app with `vue-cli 4.*` and `vue 3.0.0`.

I am trying to use this syntax that I have seen as the [proposed solution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-prop-value-in-created-method/26630)
to define complex prop types such as **Array of Objects with a specific shape**:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { PropType } from 'vue'

export default {
   props: {
      numbers: Array as PropType<Array<number>>
   }
 }
</script>
```

When I try this, and running the app via `vue-cli-service serve`, gives the error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Also **eslint** in my IDE shows as if the `as` was the issue:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   5 |   name: 'Question',
   6 |   props: {
>  7 |     numbers: Array as PropType<Array<{}>>
     |                       ^
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the exact problem in this [demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-troubleshooting-proptype). I see a different linter warning: ```Don't use `{}` as a type.  @typescript-eslint/ban-types```

Comment: @tony19 that's interesting. indeed the issue you get is easily solvable, it won't happen with something like:

`numbers: Array as PropType<Array<{
        prop1: string;
        prop2: string;
      }>>`

but in my app the IDE and cli give error, in spite the set up is the same? (`"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",`)